# Android: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException on rawQuery

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteexception

Unable to detect cause of application crash. Variables `StartDate` and `lastTimeCalculateValues` are long.

`Cursor c = MyApplicationExtendsClass.database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MyApplicationExtendsClass.locationTableName + " WHERE [Date] >= '" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US).format(StartDate) + "' AND [Date] <= '" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US).format(lastTimeCalculateValues) + "' ORDER BY Id ASC", null);`

Crash output from Google play console, 5% of active users and that is all I get.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement (Native Method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement (SQLiteConnection.java:948)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare (SQLiteConnection.java:559)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare (SQLiteSession.java:603)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init> (SQLiteProgram.java:63)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init> (SQLiteQuery.java:37)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query (SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory (SQLiteDatabase.java:1493)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery (SQLiteDatabase.java:1427)
  at my.packagename.MainActivity.calculateValuesFinalFromDb (MainActivity.java:4013)
  at my.packagename.MainActivity.access$1800 (MainActivity.java:152)
  at my.packagename.MainActivity$CalculateValuesTimer.run (MainActivity.java:4112)
  at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop (Timer.java:562)
  at java.util.TimerThread.run (Timer.java:512)
```

SQLite docs for DateTime [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

```
A time string can be in any of the following formats:  
  
YYYY-MM-DD  
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM  
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS  
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS  
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM  
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS  
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS  
HH:MM  
HH:MM:SS  
HH:MM:SS.SSS  
now  
DDDDDDDDDD
```

Documentation says **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS** can be used

Comment: Is this the full error message?

Comment: Yes that's all i got from google play console, i can't reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US)
```

To

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US)
```

This is the default SQL format for dates.

And see my answer here: [Can't get data from date to date SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64662784/cant-get-data-from-date-to-date-sqlite/64662974#64662974)

---

Update:

First part of your link:

```
SQLite supports five date and time functions as follows:

1. date(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
2. time(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
3. datetime(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
4. julianday(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
5. strftime(format, timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
```

To get presicion in milliseconds you could use following conversion:

```
CAST((julianday('your_date') - 2440587.5)*86400000 As INTEGER)
```

Explanation:

1. `julianday('your_date')` returns number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C.
2. `julianday('your_date') - 2440587.5` returns number of days in Epoch time (1970)
3. `*86400000` converts it to milliseconds (24* 60* 60* 1000)

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574784/sqlite-current-timestamp-with-milliseconds).

Then you can do Integer comparison with `>=` or also with `BETWEEN .. AND ..`

Comment: What format have the dates in your database?
Did you check the link?

Comment: The format of the date column in the database is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and I'm trying to record with milliseconds and it works since SQLite obviously ignores that part. I checked in the database and it doesn't exist. I don’t believe this is a problem because in that case the app would not work. The problem occurs with less than 5% of users and I cannot reproduce it. I checked the link, your suggestion is not acceptable to me because I need precision in milliseconds or in the worst case in seconds and not in days.

Comment: alright, have a look at my update, it should allow you to use millisecond precision

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try but I can't now, I have some urgent modification on another application. I report the result when I try.